# Calculating magnetic field from polarized electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves

My question is very simple: let a plane monochromatic electromagnetic wave's electric field be:

$$\vec{E}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-i\end{pmatrix}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$

as you can see, the electric field is completely polarized (circular polarization) and I want to obtain its corresponding magnetic field. Therefore, I simply apply:

$$\vec{B}=\frac{\vec{k}}{\omega}\times \vec{E} = \frac{k}{\omega}\begin{pmatrix}0\\i\\1\end{pmatrix}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$

Nonetheless, this vector is not perpendicular to the electric field, since:

$$\langle\vec{E}_0,\vec{B}_0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 \ 1 \ i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\i\\1\end{pmatrix}=2i$$

I assume I'm doing something wrong when calculating the vector product. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You just dropped a negative in the z-component of the Electric Field. The two vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: I did it on purpose, the dot product in $\mathbb{C}^3$ is defined as: $\langle u,v\rangle = u^*v$. I'm assuming this still applies to optics?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you're supposed to take the conjugate there. But if you convert the two vectors back into sines and cosines, taking the real part, you'll see they are in fact perpendicular. This may be a case of physicists defining the dot product as different from the inner product, but I would get a second opinion on it, since the full answer is eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

It’s just that $B_0$ is not equal to $(0,i,1)^T$, but $(0,1,i)^T$